# Changing update message from Newspaper child theme

Tags: customization, child-theme, updates

Maybe my question is very particular and limited to [Newspaper](https://tagdiv.com/Newspaper/) theme users.

I’m using child theme with an update server. It works fine.

I’m wondering if I can change this update message and actions just for the child theme:
[image: Update message]

Wanna do this because when I hit the Update button it actually updates the parent theme instead. I don't know if this can actually be changed from child theme or custom plugins. This message only appears under /wp-admin/themes.php

I’ve tried coding this but got unsuccessful.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I think you should ask the Newspaper theme authors, yes.

Comment: You'll need to search the theme for that text, or a small part of it in case it's split across lines, to find the relevant code. Then you'll find the Update button and see what link it creates for the action is, then you can track down the code that handles that action. And somewhere in that is what you'll need to change.

Comment: As far as I can tell Newspaper is a premium theme so without the source code we can't help you. Your best bet is to ask the authors directly, particularly if you've paid for the theme and support.

Comment: Thanks @Rup for the hint. I actually made it by changing a javascript file from the parent theme. I had to dequeue the original and enqueue a new one with my changes.